# Application pool Idenity issue for ASP in IIS7.0

Tags: security, iis-7, asp-classic

I've an issue while running asp on IIS7.0 with application pool identity set with domain user. I need a piece of code to run under browser client id(LOGON_USER variable) and remaining code under application pool identity. Can some one please help me how to setup IIS for this scenario?

I've a logonpage which needs to get details from LDAP. Since its running under Application pool idenity. its fetching details for application pool identity rather than user details. Can some one advice me how I need to configure IIS7.0 to retireve client details still running under application pool identity set to domain user

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490035/running-a-classic-asp-page-as-under-iis-account-when-windows-auth-is-enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two months of digging found a solution which was pretty simple.
1.My main application which was running under specific user identity, I left it untouched
2.I added a new virtual directory under sam application and moved on the log on page to new virtual directory.
3. Physical path credential for this application was  'pass through'. Changed the autherization to windows authentication.
4. Redirected to my page on sucessfull authentication, Needed to do minimal code changes as well

Thanks all